# Compare values in an array

Tags: arrays, perl, dbi

I am using perl to work with database queries that return multiple results like this:

```
select name,percent from table order by percent desc
```

I want to retrieve only those values in the if condition as in this code:

```
while (@data=$sth->fetchrow_array()) {
    $toto = $data[0];
    $percent = $data[1];
    foreach $percent (@data) {
        if ($percent > 80) {
            $output .= $toto.'='.$percent.'%,';
            $state = "BAD";
        }
        elsif ($percent > 60 && $percent < 80){
            $output .= $toto.'='.$percent.'%,';
            $state = "NOTGOOD";
        }
    }
}
my $str = "$state $output";
# Display Ouptut
print $str."\n";
undef($str);

exit $ERRORS{$status};
```

This code only prints the last statement (`NOTGOOD`); I would like to print `BAD` for each missing value.

here is the result of the query:

```
test 40
test2 80
test3 75
test4 90
test5 50
test6 45
```

and here the print output:

```
NOTGOOD test4=90%,test2=80%,test3=75%,
```

all the values are good but wrong state

Comment: Always use strict. Where do you print $output and $state?

Comment: $opt_c and $opt_w are numbers, and opt_w is less than opt_c, I think the problem is printing outside the loop . I m gonna change it

Comment: I print $output and $state at the end

Comment: Ok. So given this input, exactly what output do you want?

Answer (score 3):

Your logic is very strange here. But because it's not clear whay you're trying to do, it's impossible for me to fix it for you. I can, however, hopefully explain what your current code is doing in the hope that you can work out how to fix it.

Let's assume that your query returns the following data:

- **Name,Percent**
- John,100
- Paul,75
- George,50
- Ringo,25

Now let's step through your code a line at a time.

```
while (@data=$sth->fetchrow_array()) {
```

At this point, `@data` contains "John" and "100".

```
$toto = $data[0];
$percent = $data[1];
```

This puts "John" into `$toto` and "100" into `$percent`.

```
foreach $percent (@data) {
```

This is weird. It iterates over `@data` putting each element in turn into `$percent`. So on the first iteration `$percent` gets set to "John" (overwriting the "100" that you previously put there.

```
    if ($percent > $opt_c) {
```

I don't know what `$opt_c` contains. Let's assume it's 50. But `$percent` contains "John" - which isn't a number. If you have `use warnings` turned on (and you really should), then Perl will give you a warning at this point as you're trying to do a numerical comparison with something that isn't a number. But Perl will convert your non-number to 0 and do the comparison. 0 isn't greater than 50, so the `else` branch is executed.

```
        $output .= $toto.'='.$percent.'%,';
        $state = "BAD";
    }
    elsif ($percent > $opt_w && $percent < $opt_c){
```

Again, I don't know what `$opt_w` is. Let's assume it's 25. But `$percent` is still 0 when treated as a number. So this code isn't executed either.

```
        $output .= $toto.'='.$percent.'%,';
        $state = "NOTGOOD";
    }
}
```

}

The next time round your inner loop, `$percent` is set to 100. So your `if` code is executed and `$outer` gets set to "John=100%". And `$state` is set to "BAD". But you never do anything with `$state`, so it gets overwritten the next time round your outer (`while`) loop.

Your `foreach $percent (@data)` line is extremely questionable. I'm really not sure what you're trying to do there. And the reason that you only ever see one `$state` is because you're (presumably) printing it outside of the loop and only seeing the final value that it gets set to.

It's always a good idea to turn on `use strict` and `use warnings`. And then to fix the errors that they will show you.

Comment: I use strict and warning and I don't have any errors

Comment: Then I very much doubt that you're running the code that you're showing us here.

Comment: Running your code I get warnings like 'Argument "test" isn't numeric in numeric gt (>)'. I don't know how you don't see those warnings.

Comment: my mistake I removed use warnings and I get the same error .... How to get rid of it ?